# Как использовать urlib для адреса с кириллицей

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

Как правильно использовать `urlib.request` для получения кода страницы, при условии, что в URL есть кириллица

UPD. Есть функция:

```
def get_html(url):
    return urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

Она отдает html-код страницы по URL (да-да, кэп).
Она работает ровно до того момента как в заголовке появляется кириллица и интерпретатор отдает ошибку:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10-18: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @D-side Дополнил

Comment: "в заголовке" - это где? В HTTP-заголовке ответа или в URL?

Comment: @tutankhamun это в url

Comment: не относится к вопросу, но близко: если кодировка html указана в http content-type заголовке, то  можно [`response.headers.get_content_charset(None)` кодировку использовать, где `response = urlopen(url)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592894)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В рамках протокола HTTP не-ASCII символы в URI не допускаются. Например кириллица может быть введена и отображена в адресной строке браузера, но браузер переводит эту строку запроса (в виде [IRI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier)) в правильный, с точки зрения протокола HTTP URI. Соответственно для имени хоста применяется [Punycode](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode), а для остальных компонентов [URL-кодирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_URL).

В вашем случае можно воспользоваться дополнительной функцией для перевода из кириллического IRI в ASCII URI

```
from urllib.parse import quote, urlsplit, urlunsplit

def iri_to_uri(iri):
    parts = urlsplit(iri)
    uri = urlunsplit((
        parts.scheme, 
        parts.netloc.encode('idna').decode('ascii'), 
        quote(parts.path),
        quote(parts.query, '='),
        quote(parts.fragment),
    ))
    return uri
```

И вызывать вашу функцию так:

```
content = get_html(iri_to_uri(url))
```

Comment: (1) idna и punycode из одной тематики, но это разные вещи: следует `idna` использовать ([чтобы не путать людей, не упоминайте punycode](https://goo.gl/XuMQPX)). (2) IDNA (Internationalizing Domain Names in Applications) только к именам доменов следует применять (как следует из имени). Хотя `netloc`, который включает только порт также работает в этом случае. Если имя пользователя/пароль присутствуют (`http://user:passwd@host:port`), то может сломаться. (3) в `query` части как минимум нужно `&` разрешить (`?k1=v1&k2=v2`), а лучше из словаря с  помощью `urlencode()` получить.

Comment: @tutankhamun Спасибо